# DataTables error 'Failed to execute appendChild()'

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

```
Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element is null. jquery.tools.min.js:38
f.extend.clean jquery.tools.min.js:38
f.buildFragment jquery.tools.min.js:38
f.fn.extend.domManip jquery.tools.min.js:38
f.fn.extend.append jquery.tools.min.js:37
_fnFeatureHtmlLength jquery.dataTables.js:3209
_fnAddOptionsHtml jquery.dataTables.js:2099
_fnInitialise jquery.dataTables.js:3083
(anonymous function) jquery.dataTables.js:6301
e.extend.each jquery.tools.min.js:36
e.fn.e.each jquery.tools.min.js:36
DataTable jquery.dataTables.js:5838
(anonymous function) index.php?r=rfp:148
n jquery.tools.min.js:36
o.fireWith jquery.tools.min.js:36
e.extend.ready jquery.tools.min.js:36
c.addEventListener.B jquery.tools.min.js:36
```

One issue is that I am using getElementbyId for an onclick function that is not on the page but is elsewhere (does an ajax call). That's probably what's causing the error. I'm wondering how I can keep that and fix this error some how?

EDIT: Added sample code below with one sample row (there are many)

```
<table id="main_table" class="dataTable no-footer">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Stuff</td>
            <td>More Stuff</td>
            <td>Even more stuff</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr role="row">
            <td onclick="document.getElementById("cdid").value=232; document.getElementById("viewForm").submit();"> ... </td>
            <td> more things </td>
            <td> even more things </td>
        </tr>
        ...
        More rows of the same format
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: How do you expect us to help fix your code, if we can't see your code?
Please add the relevant sections of your code to the question, so we can look for the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question with sample code

Comment: There's no `appendChild` in that code...

Comment: First of all, you forgot to escape double quotes in `onclick`. Should be  `onclick="document.getElementById('cdid').value=232; document.getElementById('viewForm').submit();"`

Comment: Yeah... it's because of `dataTables`. When I added dataTables to this that's the error that's coming up. The `appendChild` is likely in the dataTables jQuery file.

@nicael it's just a messup on this example, it's not like that on the actual table code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the similar problem with jQuery dataTables. I resolved it somehow by changing the jQuery version. Previously, I was using jQuery of version 1.6.4

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

But, later, I changed it to the latest version, jquery-1.11.0

`<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

The error got vanished and I could see my tables. Please check what version of jQuery you are using, and change it to latest version. If you had the same problem like me, this solution would help.

And also make sure, dataTables require, jquery.js but not jquery.tools.js, if you are using jquery.tools.js, then change it to jquery.js (latest version) and see whether it worked.

Hope this helps,
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I upgraded from 1.7.1 to 1.8.3 and it fixed the issue for me. I didn't jump to 1.11.0 due to possible compatibility issues outlined on the jQuery website.